# Does the "joint probability" of two events take their order into account?

Tags: probability

When we speak of "joint probabilities" in a general sense, do they take the order in which the events occur into account? Or alternatively, is it -by defnition- true that

$P(A\cap B) = P(B\cap A)$

? My [statistics book](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/pearsonhigheredus/educator/product/products_detail.page?isbn=0135131995) is not explicit on this and I can't deduce it from the examples given.

A reference that's explicit on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you have from ensemble theory that $A \cap B = B \cap A$ (for instance from the intersection definition there [Intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))), which is intuitive : $A \cap B$ is the set of elements that are both in A and B.
Therefore  $\mathbb{P} (B \cap A)= \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) $. And indeed the joint distribution is just for a pair of values to happen, no matter how they are related.

If you are interested in the order of elements, you are probably more interested in **conditional probability** (there should be a chapter on that in your book), that is

$$
\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}
$$

which is the probability that $A$ occurs given that B has occured

Comment: I'm familiar with that rule but there's something I don't get with regard to this situation: if my sample space S = {AAABBB} and I draw twice from it without replacement, then the rule states that $P(A)$ = 0.5 and $P(B|A)$ = 0.6 so $P(A\cap B)$ = 0.3. However, this doesn't take into account the 0.3 probability of drawing A and B in the reverse order so $P(A \cap B)$ *really* is 0.6 and not 0.3. What am I missing here?

Comment: In the probability nmodel you are using, there is NO concept of "time"! **Everything** 'happens' simultaneously, the order you see in formulas like $P(A|B)$ is **not** a time order.

Comment: You are not stating the problem correctly. In the example you give you have to separate the two draws : you have one random variable, let us name it $X_1$, that is the first drax, and and another one for the second draw, be $X_2$. Then, you want to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X_2=B|X_1=A)$, which is equal to $\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_2 = B \cap X_1 = A)}{\mathbb{P}(X_1=A)} = \frac{1/2*3/5}{1/2} = \frac{3}{5}$

Comment: @Aerandal: you're totally right. Indeed, adding the subscripts to indicate two separate the different probability experiments really solves the riddle.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: I see how that works for events based on a single experiment: if I draw 1 person from a database, what's the probability she owns a car -given the person is female. But in the case of sampling 2 out of 6 colored balls, the conditional probability for the color of the second ball necessarily does involve a time order, right?

Comment: RubenGeert: yes, but that order is in your interpretation of the formula, not in the mathematics!